# Running Hadoop jobs on YARN - Killing container

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, ambari

I'm having problem running Hadoop jobs on YARN, concretely on Ambari. I'm new to Hadoop, have written MR jobs, but have no experience in cluster administration.

I'm trying to run WordCount example for a small input file (like 1.4MB) and most of the time I get an exception like the following:

```
Application application_1453983463294_0005 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1453983463294_0005_000002 exited with exitCode: -104
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://hdp-master.nissatech.local:8088/cluster/app/application_1453983463294_0005Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Container [pid=23429,containerID=container_1453983463294_0005_02_000001] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 264.6 MB of 256 MB physical memory used; 1.9 GB of 537.6 MB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

It seems that I should change heap limit. I don't understand how is it possible that such amount of heap is needed for such a small job?

YARN was installed using Ambari default setup, so I haven't change any of the parameters. This is a small cluster with 4 machines, 3 of which are used as DataNodes/NodeManagers (and have RegionServers which are not used at the moment). Each worker has 4GB of RAM and 4 cores.

What is the concrete problem and how to solve it?

Additionally, I would be thankful for any reference which could help me understand how to setup and configure a small cluster (e.g. up to 10 machines). By that I mean what amount of RAM and CPU to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the container being killed is the AM, not the job. That would be the Application Manager, in other words the "map-reduce" app running on your Yarn. This means that it does no matter how simple the WordCount sample is, is not the offending container.

Can you check the configured value for `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb`? The [default](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml) is 1.5GB and it appears that your cluster is configured to not allow containers over 256Mb. What is the configured `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`?

I'm not sure how Ambari configured your cluster resources, but looks like you'll have to tune it manually. Follow a guide like [How to Plan and Configure YARN and MapReduce 2 in HDP 2.0](http://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/) or [Tuning the Cluster for MapReduce v2 (YARN)](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I increased values the problem was gone. I changed values "Minimum Container Size (Memory)" from 256MB to 512MB and "Maximum Container Size (Memory)" from 2048MB to 3072MB. What is strange is that it did not go to the upper limit, but used the lower one of 256MB. I'm guessing that this was too small. This value was set by default.

Comment: Can you please explain the values for the worker node in this examples, why are they so big? Is this what is really used in reality? It says "The following table shows example demand estimates for a worker node with 24 vcores and 256 GB of memory.", I thought that Hadoop is about commodity hw. By commodity I consider something like 4 cores and 4 GB RAM for worker node. Am I that wrong?

Comment: Is best to refer to your specific distribution manual, eg. https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/determine-hdp-memory-config.html